# How to check a given date was within a x number of days in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, date-difference

Given a variable for number of days and a specific date,
how can we check if the date given is within the past number of days.

In other words how can I check if **dateVar** was within the last 7 days or whatever the value of number is.

```
var number = 7

var dateVar = "29-11-2016 13:21:33"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to convert you date string to `Date` object and then you can use `DateComponent` to find the difference between that date and current date in days and compare that days with you number, something like this.

```
let dateVar = "29-11-2016 13:21:33"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateVar) {
    print(date)
    let numberOfDays = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: Date()).day ?? 0
    print(numberOfDays)
    if numberOfDays <= number {
         print("DateVar with in number of days")
    }
}
```

Comment: @SwiftStarter Welcome mate :)

Comment: @NiravD There is nothing in that string saying that the TimeZone is GMT.  You shouldn't set it manually to GMT. TimeZone is and should always be local time when using date formatter if not explicitly specified in the string.

Comment: @NiravD no need to deal with it, just delete that line