# How to identify objects in array with Date range in last 7 days?

Tags: swift

I know there are a lot of questions about dates and using/comparing dates within Swift, but I didn't see this specific question addressed.

Here is my issue, I have an array with objects in it, one of the object properties is a Date object created (`createdDate = Date()`)when the record was saved. I'd like to be able to select the records that have a date from within the past X days (7, 28, etc.).

Not sure where to start any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create another Date (`dateMinusXDays`) using `(NS)Calendar` usefull methods, then it's just about a using `filter()` correctly on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863559/how-to-check-a-given-date-was-within-a-x-number-of-days-in-swift-3 is one possible starting point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift has powerful tools to work with arrays. In you case you need filter your array.

```
let keyDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -7 * 60 * 60 * 24)
let filteredArray = originalArray.filter{ $0.createdDate > keyDate }
```

Check for more: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Edit:
Regarding obtaining keyDate - if you exactly last 7days * 24hours * 60minutes * 60seconds - use timeIntervalSince now.  If you need date based not on seconds, but by calendar, then:

```
let keyDate = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
```

more details at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293676-date

Comment: Never use 60 * 60 * 24 seconds as the duration of a day, think of DST transitions. Always use the proper Calendar methods.

Comment: Depends on what you need. If you need something happened during last 24/48/72 hours etc. then time interval is perfect.